# Rails Device omniauth SSL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I am getting the following error when I tried to auth a user using `omniauth` for Facebook.

`Faraday::SSLError
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

I have copied `cacert.pem` into my config folder and on my `development.rb` I set it as

`ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + "/config/cacert.pem"`

I even tried to follow this method [Github fix](https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550), but the problem still persist. I am running rails app on windows machine. Thanks